# Alternatives to std::array for objects of different types in C++11

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, memory-management

I am looking for better solutions on how to organize and access my data.
My data is a set of structures (`_array_10` and `_array_20` in the example below) that contain `std::array` of different sizes (see `my_data` below).
Ideally, I would like to access it as it was an array of structs with different lengths, but this is not allowed, since different lengths are different types.
The solution I have below works, but I find it extremely ugly (specially the array of `void *`).

Q1. Any ideas on how to have a safer, more efficient/portable, or at least less ugly solution?
Q2. Is the proposed solution without templates portable? It relies on the fact that the length is stored before the rest of the data, since casting the pointer to an object with wrong length would mess the access to all fields that come after the first field of variable length.

My limitations include:

- C++11
- standard libraries
- no `std::vector`
- memory usage prevents me from being able to simply allocate an array of `my_data` with the maximum possible length
- the bulk of the data (`_array_10`, `_array_20`, etc) will be placed in a memory area reserved specially for it

Using data_view and template require knowledge of the length of the arrays in build time. It would be great if we could avoid it.

- Question edited to include the solution proposed by Guillaume Racicot

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

std::array<void *, 2> _ptrs;

template <int length>
struct my_data
{
    int                     array_length;
    std::array<int, length> something;
    std::array<int, length> data;
    my_data()
    {
        array_length = length;
    }
};


struct my_data_view
{
    int         array_length;
    const int * something;
    const int * data;

    template <int length>
    my_data_view(my_data<length> const & data_in) :
        array_length(length),
        something(data_in.something.data()),
        data(data_in.data.data())
    {}
};

template <int length>
void
print_element(int array_idx, int element)
{
    my_data<length> * ptr = reinterpret_cast<my_data<length> *>(_ptrs[array_idx]);

    std::cout << "array " << length << ", data[" << element << "] = " << ptr->data[element] << ".\n";
}

void
print_element(int array_idx, int element)
{
    my_data<1> * ptr    = reinterpret_cast<my_data<1> *>(_ptrs[array_idx]);
    int          length = ptr->array_length;

    int data_to_print = 0;
    switch (length)
    {
        case 10:
        {
            data_to_print = reinterpret_cast<my_data<10> *>(_ptrs[array_idx])->data[element];
            break;
        }
        case 20:
        {
            data_to_print = reinterpret_cast<my_data<20> *>(_ptrs[array_idx])->data[element];
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "array " << length << ", data[" << element << "] = " << data_to_print << ".\n";
}

void
print_element(my_data_view view, int element)
{
    int length        = view.array_length;
    int data_to_print = view.data[element];

    std::cout << "array " << length << ", data[" << element << "] = " << data_to_print << ".\n";
}

int
main()
{
    my_data<10> _array_10;
    my_data<20> _array_20;

    _ptrs[0] = static_cast<void *>(&_array_10);
    _ptrs[1] = static_cast<void *>(&_array_20);

    _array_10.data[5] = 11;
    _array_20.data[5] = 22;

    std::cout << "using template\n";
    print_element<10>(0, 5);
    print_element<20>(1, 5);

    std::cout << "\nwithout template\n";
    print_element(0, 5);
    print_element(1, 5);

    std::cout << "\nusing data_view\n";
    print_element(my_data_view(_array_10), 5);
    print_element(my_data_view(_array_20), 5);
}
```

Comment: You don't really have any viable options. You need C++17 and `std::variant`. I see no "better solutions" otherwise.

Comment: std::variant to store std::array of different size is abuse :-) The variant will have the size of the biggest used type. So you can expand all the used arrays to max size to have the same result. Far away from being efficient!

Comment: Why tagging memory-management, whereas you seems that lifetime of `_array_10`/`_array_20` is not the issue of `_ptrs`?

Comment: I understand the question is about ways to organize your potentially large data. Can you suggest a tag that is more appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a dynamic view class that don't allocate:

```
struct my_data_view
{
    int array_length;
    std::span<int> something;
    std::span<int> data;

    template<int length>
    my_data_view(my_data<length> const& data) : 
        array_length{length}, something{data.something}, data{data.data}
    {}
};
```

Spans simply are a pointer and a size. If you don't have access to `std::span` (which is from C++20) you can simply replace those member with `int*` and use `array_length` for the size.

This `my_data_view` type is used like that:

```
void
print_element(my_data_view view, int element)
{
    int length = view.array_length;
    int data_to_print = view.data[element];

    std::cout << "array " << length << ", data[" << element << "] = " << data_to_print << ".\n";
}
```

This is the code that will work both with `std::span` and simple `int*`.

Comment: @Jarod42 it's also mostly redundant with the 2 `std::array`, yet OP did wrote it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is definitely an interesting solution, but it still require knowledge of the length of the arrays in build time to use the objects. Also, if we want to iterate over the arrays _array_10 and _array_20, we would still need the array of void *.

Comment: @Eduardo the way you check the size has undefined behaviour. You'll have to change it or there will be crashes or worse, wrong calculations without crashes.

Comment: @Eduardo: You no longer need `void*`, you might have array of `my_data_view` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cdc6bf140744450).